# Acceder a las líneas de un dataframe con índices anidados

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Tengo un dataframe `sales_monthly` que tiene índices anidados y me gustaria acceder a las líneas de una pareja (shop_id, item_id).

```
                                date                    item_price  item_cnt_day
                                min         max         mean        sum
date_block_num  shop_id item_id             
0               0       32      2013-01-03  2013-01-31  221.0       6.0
                        33      2013-01-03  2013-01-28  347.0       3.0
                        35      2013-01-31  2013-01-31  247.0       1.0
                        43      2013-01-31  2013-01-31  221.0       1.0
                        51      2013-01-13  2013-01-31  128.5       2.0
... ... ... ... ... ... ...
33              59      22087   2015-10-05  2015-10-23  119.0   6.0
                        22088   2015-10-03  2015-10-27  119.0   2.0
                        22091   2015-10-03  2015-10-03  179.0   1.0
                        22100   2015-10-18  2015-10-18  629.0   1.0
                        22102   2015-10-16  2015-10-16  1250.0  1.0
```

Intenté accederlo con:

```
for i, row in test.iterrows():
  print(sales_monthly.loc[sales_monthly['shop_id'] == row['shop_id']])
```

Pero me devuelve:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2897             try:
-> 2898                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   2899             except KeyError as err:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'shop_id'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
6 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2898                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   2899             except KeyError as err:
-> 2900                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   2901 
   2902         if tolerance is not None:

KeyError: 'shop_id'
```

Aqui esta la dataframe `test` con la cual intente acceder a `sales_monthly`:

```
    ID  shop_id item_id
0   0   5   5037
1   1   5   5320
2   2   5   5233
3   3   5   5232
4   4   5   5268
```

Comment: "indicios incrustados" quiere decir _nested indexes_? En ese caso la traducción no es correcta y no se entiende, deberías decir "índices anidados", o "índices jerárquicos", o directamente el término que usa pandas: "multi-índices"

Comment: Por otro lado tampoco se entiende bien la pregunta. ¿Hay otro dataframe aparte del que muestras al principio? ¿Qué es el dataframe que muestras al final y por qué le llamas `test.py`?

Comment: @abulafia ¡Hola, Abulafia! Espero que estés bien. Sí, siento haber cometido dos errores. Modifiqué la traducción y `test` no se llama `test.py`. Es la dataframe con los indices desde las que intento acceder al `sales_monthly`.

Comment: Hola @RevolucionforMonica ! Sería bueno que en la pregunta pusieras con código mínimo reproducible que copiar y ya tener el DataFrame. Esto ayudaría mucho a los que queremos ayudarte :)